# How to associate IBOutlets to base classes?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, cocoapods, iboutlet

I would like to extract base classes from my project and put them into a CocoaPod so I can replicate and manage the projects quickly. What I am confused about is how to connect the controls from my storyboard to the base classes I place in the CocoaPod? The base classes will need references to those controls that are in the derived projects.

Comment: so is your storyboard in your CocoaPod or the derived project?

Comment: In the derived. But I'm considered to breaking up into several XIB's or make use of Xcode 7's modular storyboard feature.

Comment: If you want to add IBOutlets in the base classes, you should connect them to the controls in the derived projects everytime. or you can use code to add all controls, don't use storyboard